# Neutrons through a reactor shield

Tags: probability, physics, random-walk

I have been staring at my screen now since last Thursday. I am very new to coding and am not at all sure how to go about this problem. Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

A beam of neutrons bombards a reactor's wall. Consider the motion of the neutrons as a random walk on the (x,y) plane.

The neutrons then have to comply with the following conditions:

Only four directions of motion are possible (left, right, up or down).
On the next step the neutron can not step back, but only forward, left or right.
The probability to go forward is four times more than changing a direction.
On each step the neutron looses one unit of energy.
The initial neutron energy is enough for 100 steps.
The initial neutron velocity is perpendicular to the shield.
There are three possibilities for a neutron after entering the shield : it can return to the reactor core, it can be absorbed inside the shield or it can penetrate and travel through the shield.
When a neutron re-enters the reactor or when it goes through the shield, its random path stops, regardless of its energy.

I would share the coding I have right now, but it is doing absolutely nothing and is useless to solving the problem. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this is off-topic as written: it's very broad, as it's just a general problem statement. There are likely many ways to solve such a problem. And many languages you could solve this in.  You'd really need to edit this to include what you've tried, where you're stuck, expected vs actual output, errors, etc. Otherwise, it's just a broad set of requirements, with a request for the the community to solve it. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information about creating a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Have you tried simpler random walk problems, such as 1-D?